# Integration by substitution $\int (x - b) dx$

Tags: calculus

Probably a simple one. So, integrating something like:

$$\int (x-b) \space dx $$

Integrating by substitution seems to be the way to go, like so:

$$\frac{d}{dx} (x-b) = \frac{d}{dx}x - \frac{d}{dx} b = 1 - 0$$

Which means:

$$du = dx$$

In other words:

$$\int (x-b) \space dx = \int u \space du$$

$$\int u \space du = \frac{u^2}{2} + c = \frac{(x-b)^2}{2} + c $$

But then I did it like this:

$$\int (x-b) \space dx = \int x \space dx - b\int 1 \space dx = \frac{x^2}{2} - bx + c$$

And all I have to say to this is: what?!

So, what am I missing? (changed variables to use the constant of integration as c, not to confuse anyone)

Comment: Try expanding your first result. Keep in mind the constant of integration is arbitrary.

Comment: As @David Mitra said the constant is *arbitrary*. That's the key in your question.

Comment: Thanks, Olivier & David , needed that confirmation. @user355304, you completely miss the point of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting $x-b=u$

$$\int (x-b) \space dx = \int u \space du$$

$$\int u \space du = \frac{u^2}{2} + c = \frac{(x-b)^2}{2} + c =\frac{x^2}{2}-bx+\left(\frac{b^2}{2}+c\right)$$

Similarly,

$$\int (x-b) \space dx = \int x \space dx - b\int 1 \space dx = \left(\frac{x^2}{2}+c_1\right)+\left(- bx +c_2\right)=\frac{x^2}{2}-bx+ C $$ as $c_1+c_2=C$

---

Notice that the constants are different.

$$\frac{b^2}{2}+c=C$$ instead of $$\frac{b^2}{2}+c=c$$

Here, $C$ is some other constant.

Comment: Ah, yes, one can "hide" the two separate constants into a larger one and just deal with that. Much obliged, had a feeling this is the case, but needed the confirmation! Thanks!